# Has or have, which form is correct?

Tags: grammatical-number, have

For me it´s not really clear, because it´s possible to keep it in singular in German.

which version correct?

The Motor front and the motor rear bearing "has" or "have" been replaced?

Thanks in advance ;)

Kind regards

Comment: So, would you say “The front and back door is locked”?

Answer (score 0):

The **m**otor front and the motor rear bearing **have** been replaced.

Comment: Thx Rufus, I thought if I count them as I did, I could write has.

Comment: It´s clear for me, if would write: The motor bearings have been replaced :)

Comment: As an aside, that would suggest to me that a "motor front" and a "motor rear bearing" are unrelated parts.  If you mean the front and rear bearings of the motor, it would be clearer to write "The motor front and rear bearings have been replaced". Or to be even less ambiguous, "The motor bearings, front and rear, have been replaced."